# (cdk + boto3): Use boto3 inside CDK application

Tags: boto3, aws-cdk

I run CDK against different environments using `ENV=<enviornment name> cdk synth --profile <PROFILE_NAME> --all` - now I want to create SSM secret parameter inside my CDK application. This should only happen during scaffolding but needs boto3 as there is no CloudFormation equivalent. How can I reuse the CDK authentication together with boto3? I develop in Python both with the CDK as with boto3 and use an MFA. Any ideas?

**#1 Trial - Using cached credentials**

> Not working as CDK is not caching credentials :(

I came a accross some way to retrive cached credentials with boto3. Still I need the profile used with CDK, as without I get the error message `botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials`. Does somebody know how to get the AWS CDK profile used within the code? Maybe the first step to a solution.

```
# By default the cache path is ~/.aws/boto/cache
cli_cache = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), ".aws/cli/cache")

# Construct botocore session with cache
session = botocore.session.get_session()
session.get_component("credential_provider").get_provider(
    "assume-role"
).cache = credentials.JSONFileCache(cli_cache)

# Create boto3 client from session
return boto3.Session(botocore_session=session)
```

Comment: This is a bad practice, you should not make any network calls during synth.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/best-practices-for-developing-cloud-applications-with-aws-cdk/

Why not use a `ssm.StringParameter` construct, or better yet, a `secretsmanager.Secret`?

Comment: Since you already know the context, why not pass the profile as a context parameter, its easy and recommended way to get access to dynamic parameters to CDK CLI. refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/context.html

Comment: @gshpychka how can I do it after the synth - are there lifecycle hooks I did not see?

Comment: @TechFree thought about this as well, but a) I have funnelled the profile to CDK then and am not sure how to do this, b) this way I would have to enter the MFA a second time.

Comment: You can't, you would do it as part of the synth, just like any other CDK cosntruct.

Comment: @gshpychka just to clear this up - I do not want to commit secrets and keep them in my code base. But if I scaffold an application, secrets have to be added as well. But thanks for your answer - even I do not like to take the no for an answer :)

Comment: Add secrets during the synth phase, just as any CDK construct. Your CDK code should not make any network calls itself.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest looking into [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/custom-resources-readme.html), it is a way to call AWS api's (or even execute any code) inside of CDK.

Comment: Is there a new way to do this with CDK v2? It appears that the custom_resources module no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is using Lambda. In this [example](https://github.com/srijitm/sample-rds-infra/blob/master/lib/rds-infra-stack.ts), you can see how tables were created after provisioning RDS. In your case you can replace table creation with SSM secret parameter creation.

Comment: isn't that the custom resources way?

Comment: In general sense, yes